# FLOAT values loaded from CSV are not parsed correctly

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a CSV file which I am loading to BigQuery using this schema:

```
[
  {"name": "l1", "type": "float", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name": "l2", "type": "float", "mode": "nullable"},
]
```

My data looks like this:

```
40.7125,-73.8154
34.1007,-81.227
34.1003,-81.2273
```

After loading the data into BigQuery, it becomes like this:

```
40.712501525878906,-73.81539916992188
34.10070037841797,-81.22699737548828    
34.10029983520508,-81.22730255126953
```

How this is possible? Where all the extra digits are coming from?

Comment: It looks like a bug (pretty serious one) in loading from CSV file. Converting the data file to JSON and reloading to BigQuery results in correct data in the table.

Comment: Numbers are the same, well, they are after rounding. writing down 40.7125 is not the same as 40.71250000000000000, so one of your algorithms just fills in the blanks..

Comment: Which algorithm? I am just loading the data as-us...

Comment: loading data is by itself an algorithm. It looks like these numbers are gps coordinates. Either accept the (minor) difference and use them as is, or preformat them using more accuracy

Comment: @dmaij - considering I need to do calculations based on these numbers, can you suggest a way of trimming the extra digits? I don't know upfront how many digits will be in the CSV file...

Comment: That depends on the language you are using, for instance in php you could use this: floatval(numberformat($var, 6)). But how much does it hurt your answers when using the values as is?

Comment: That is what float is by definition an inexact representation of numbers, it si why I do not allow people use it on SQL server at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data, the 'extra' digits can be removed by rounding to 5 digits after the decimal point.  In a BigQuery query that's ROUND(value, 5) or you can do it in another language as commented above.  When the data is lat/long degrees, rounding to 5 digits is about 1 meter on the Earth.

Or if you can re-import your data now, it will have full precision (meaning IEEE double float).  This issue came from a change to the BigQuery import system, which we have turned off and are investigating.  Thank you for the report.

Comment: I will try to reload now and will report result soon.

Comment: I can confirm that the reloading the data indeed solves the problem. The FLOAT values are now correct and do not include random extra digits. Anything we can/should do to avoid this kind of the problem in the future?

Comment: Nope, this really wasn't anything you could have avoided.  Noticing it and asking the question was a good response.  Thanks for confirming it's working for you now.